# How to submit mapreduce job remotely

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have set up a hadoop2 cluster, and I can submit the wordcount example job using "hadoop jar" command. Now I want to combine the hadoop cluster with a java web app, which means I can submit the job whose jar file already existing in the HDFS to the cluster.
My question is:
1.Should I configure the hadoop environment in my web server?
2.Should I configure the hadoop environment in my java app code?
3.Is there an official tutorial about remote submission in apache?

I'm new to hadoop, I'm using hadoop 2.9.2.

I just know the code about the wordcount example, and I package the source code to a jar using maven in windows, but I still cannot run it using "hadoop jar", the error is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount". I have no idea about it at all now.
Here is my code:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.3.100:9000");
    conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "192.168.3.100");
    // conf.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "192.168.3.100:9001");
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
    // conf.set("yarn.application.classpath", "$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,"
    //         +"$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,"
    //         +"$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,"
    //         +"$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,"
    //         +"$YARN_HOME/*,$YARN_HOME/lib/*,"
    //         +"$HBASE_HOME/*,$HBASE_HOME/lib/*,$HBASE_HOME/conf/*");

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/zhangke/data/data.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/output"));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

I really want to work it out, thank you!

Comment: Please show your entire `hadoop jar` command.

Comment: @BenWatson the command has error is "hadoop jar word-count-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar WordCount /zhangke/data/data.txt /output1", I package the word-count-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar via maven

Comment: You're missing the full package to WordCount

Comment: @BenWatson Thank you!  It really works! And I truly want to know the solution of the three questions I mentioned above, do you know the answer? The most important one is how to launch a job whost jar file is existed in the hdfs.